# Update view of component after value changes in service

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have a toolbar with `_toolbarTitle` in it which I want to update after `title` in my toolbar title service changes. It changes after navigating to a different page by using `setToolbarTitle()`.  I've tried using observables but struggled to implement it correctly.

**toolbar-title.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ToolbarTitleService {
  title: string = 'toolbarTitle';
  constructor() {}

  setToolbarTitle(title) {
    this.title = title;
  }

  getToolbarTitle() {
    return this.title;
  }
}
```

**toolbar.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { ToolbarTitleService } from '../services/toolbar-title.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-toolbar',
  templateUrl: './toolbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./toolbar.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class ToolbarComponent implements OnInit {
  _toolbarTitle = '';
  constructor(private toolbarTitle: ToolbarTitleService) {}

  onClick() {
    this._toolbarTitle = this.toolbarTitle.getToolbarTitle();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._toolbarTitle = this.toolbarTitle.getToolbarTitle();
    console.log(this.toolbarTitle.getToolbarTitle());
  }
}
```

**toolbar.component.html**

```html
<ion-toolbar color="primary">
  <ion-buttons slot="start">
    <ion-back-button defaultHref="/login"></ion-back-button>
  </ion-buttons>

  <ion-title> {{ _toolbarTitle }} </ion-title>

  <img src="assets/specto_logo.svg" />
</ion-toolbar>
```

Comment: Can you share how you are using the title in your html?

Comment: @eko updated it with html now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so it's probably not changing because of your `OnPush` `ChangeDetectionStrategy`.

Let's build it with observables:

service

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ToolbarTitleService {
  title = new BehaviorSubject('toolbarTitle');

  setToolbarTitle(title) {
    this.title.next(title);
  }
}
```

component

```js
export class ToolbarComponent implements OnInit {
  _toolbarTitle = this.toolbarTitle.title;
  constructor(private toolbarTitle: ToolbarTitleService) {}
//...
}
```

html

```html
<ion-toolbar color="primary">
  <ion-buttons slot="start">
    <ion-back-button defaultHref="/login"></ion-back-button>
  </ion-buttons>

  <ion-title> {{ _toolbarTitle | async }} </ion-title>

  <img src="assets/specto_logo.svg" />
</ion-toolbar>
```

So with observables, you don't need to "get" your title because since it's a stream the `async` pipe in the html will continuously "observe" the changes

Comment: Awesome, it works wonderfully. Just one question though, as I'm new to frontend development/programming. Why does my toolbar display [object Object] without `| async` in the html?

Comment: I don't know how familiar you're with observables but the `async` pipe basically subscribes to the observables and gets the, let's say, latest value from them. Without the async pipe what you're trying to display is an object and the template can't display objects as-is because it doesn't know which format it should display them in. If you replace the `async` pipe with the `json` pipe (`_toolbarTitle | json`), you will see that it formats the object as a json.